# How to compute a confidence interval for AUC?

Tags: classification, auc

I found that in results of several binary classification problems, people report an AUC value together with a CI. I wonder how those CIs are computed. Is there a close-formed formula to compute them or they are computed via some method like bootstrap?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to calculate it in any other way than experimentally (e.g. bootstrap), but I'm not sure.